# How to filter columns in numpy ndarray

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array of `booleans` that says which columns of another array I should drop.

For example:

```
selections = [True, False, True]
data = [[ 1, 2, 3 ],
        [ 4, 5, 6 ]]
```

I would like to have the following one:

```
new_data = [[ 1, 3 ],
            [ 4, 6 ]
```

All arrays are  `numpy.array` in Python 2.7.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Once you actually use `numpy.array`s, it all works:

```
import numpy as np

selections = np.array([True, False, True])
data = np.array([[ 1, 2, 3 ],
        [ 4, 5, 6 ]])

>>> data[:, selections]
array([[1, 3],
       [4, 6]])
```